# Why Firebase event takes about 5 seconds before getting visible in network logs?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I'm logging events using firebase analytics and it's taking about 5 seconds before I can see it in the network logs from the inspect elements. Upon diving deeper I did come to the observation that following function call is consuming the said time:

```
window.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent()
```

Can anyone please help me with it to minimise the event log trigger time?

Answer (score 0):

only a Firebaser would be able to answer this technical question, I suggest contacting [**support**](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) who can elevate it with a technician.

Comment: If you do find an answer, I would love to know.

Comment: Not yet, will let you know ASA I get it.